# Replicating two or more oracle tables in one flat data structure in Redis

Tags: oracle, redis, debezium

I have two tables in oracle employee_info and employee_detail and want to replicate data of both the tables into single data structure(JSON- preferably) in Redis .

I don't want to create Materialized view on oracle side .

Is there any way to replicate two Oracle table data in single data structure in Redis and keep replicating when ever there is change in any of the source table .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Redis OSS or Redis Enterprise?
For Redis OSS you can use RedisGears for post-processing. Basically you will sync each table to a separate set of keys and perform a 'join-like' operation when fetching to build a JSON document
If you are using Redis Enterprise, Redis offers Redis Data Integration which can accomplish merging two source tables into a single document.

Comment: I am using enterprise - can you please share the link where it demonstrate how RDI is merging two or more source tables into a single document .
Once the merge is done on single document i am looking for CDC too (whenever there is any change in source table does CDC will work on that single doc).